# Integrated testing vs Isolated testing in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

1. What are the major differences between **Integrated testing**
   against **Isolated testing** ?
2. When are these used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Integrated Testing

- Involves more efforts for

  1. Setting up the component to test (using [TestBed](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html))
  2. Check which are the child components and custom components
  3. Configure the properties and methods in those child (or) custom components, which throws error if failed
- Even for a simple scenario **`involves more time`** as each and every property or their bindings has to be tested separately. This increases either of the below

  1. number of **`it`** blocks
  2. number of **`expect`** statements in a single **`it`** block
- Attracts or **`tempts`** to **`write more test cases`** as reason is in the second bullet
- **No** **`Pipes`** or **`Services`** are tested.

## Isolated Testing

- No configuration is needed to test (including components)
- **`Handles logic which has low complexity`** there by testing only the parent component and not worried about the child components.
- For complex properties and bindings can be easily tested because the entire object can be passed into an **`expect`** statement which reduces the number of test cases unlike above.
- Mainly used for unit testing the **`Pipes`** and **`Services`** as their functionality is completely independent